# SpriteKit make images fit screen, not stretch past

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sizing

I'm working on a project, and SKNodes aren't resizing dynamically based on device size.

Example:

[image: Image one]
[image]

I'd like what happens on the first image to happen in the second.
Is there anything to make this happen automatically?

Current sizing for image shown:

```
    background.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2)
    background.size = CGSize(width: background.size.width / 5.5, height: background.size.height / 5.5)
```

GameViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false

    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

    scene.controller = self
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    skView.presentScene(scene)
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your whole scene to resize when the game is presented on device with a larger screen you just need to open `GameViewController.swift` and make sure you are using `AspectFill`

```
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

Comment: I already have this line of code in my GameViewController.. weird. Maybe it's being ignored? @appzYourLife